# Why window.navigator.plugins is undefined?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Noticed that window.navigator.plugins in my selenium tests always is null, not depends - use I profile with already installed plugins or install them by add_extension function.

selenium == 2.53.1
firefox == 46.0.b9

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Can you provide code examples, what you've tried, etc.?  I can't tell from your question what it is you are even looking for.

Comment: @BillHileman if you run selenium test, and use firefox webdriver, open browser console(aka firebug) and type window.navigator.plugins you get empty object {}. My question - Why webdriver not show plugins and how to fix it

Comment: That is by design.  I believe you will find that all supported Selenium web drivers do not support plug-ins or add-ons of any kind.  This is almost always preferable.  I do wish myself that firebug/firepath and other similar tools were available with a webdriver run, but to my knowledge it is not possible.

Comment: @BillHileman you can easy use any add-on with selenium
`profile.add_extension('firebug-2.0.18-fx.xpi')`. My question why they don't show in navigator.plugins

Comment: Good to know, thank you.  It may still have something to do with it being by design.  Since the profile is only read at initialization, it may not want the user (tester) to be able to change the capabilities of the browser while it is running.  In that way, perhaps its a fail-safe.  Are you in a situation where you need to activate/add a plug-in for a test?  If so, you may need to close the running instance and create a new one with the plug-in extension added at test time.